# QGLWidget - how to structure a program with overpainting

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, graphics, qglwidget

This should be simple: I'm using a QGLWidget to draw some openGL graphics and I want to be able to write something on the openGL graphics rendered, so I'm using overpainting as in the Qt demo with QPainter.

Here are my two working choices of structuring my program:

```
// This works but it's probably stupid
paintEvent()
{

    makeCurrent();

    glewInit();

    loadShaders();

    loadTextures();

    loadBuffers();

    ... actually paint something with openGL ...

    QPainter painter(this);

    ... overpainting ...
}

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// This works and may probably be better
paintEvent()
{

    QGLWidget::paintEvent(event); // Base class call, this calls initializeGL ONCE and then paintGL each time it's needed

    QPainter painter(this);

    ... overpainting ...
}

initializeGL()
{
    glewInit();
}

paintGL()
{
    loadShaders();

    loadTextures();

    loadBuffers();

    ... actually paint something with openGL ...
}
```

Considering that textures and shaders aren't going to be always the same, is any of these options acceptable (in performances and reasonably)?

If not: how would you structure the program?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. load/compile/link shaders in the `initializeGL()` method, because that is relatively slow operation (specially if it is read from the disk)
2. load textures in the `initializeGL()` method

Not sure what are buffers, but sounds like it should be done in the initialization, since it is done only once.

Comment: is it okay to load glew there? I didn't find another place to load glew

Comment: Notice: the paintEvent is raised multiple times, unfortunately seems that moving the shaders/textures/buffers(VBO) code into initializeGL (which is called just at the change of context) causes the app not to be rendered well

Comment: @JohnnyPauling Not really. glew should be in the main, because it needs argc/argv from the main()

Comment: damn, for some reason it crashes in the main.. I'll try again tomorrow but the only place I found to load glew with QGLWidget without problems is initializeGL

Comment: @JohnnyPauling Right. if you are changing context, then you should do it in the constructor, not in `initializeGL()`

Comment: You generally can't initialise shaders or CUDA until you have a glContext initialised. But it avoids doing this until you have a widget being repainted. SO initialiseGL is often the last thing called before the first repaint